# how to open url in p:dialog?

Tags: primefaces

I want something like this.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="ex.show()"></h:commandButton>


<p:dialog id="dialog1"  widgetVar="ex">
   <h:output Text value="Hi"/>
</p:dialog>
```

This opens the pop up with hi text inside the p:dialog. But I need to open an url in that popup. How can I approach?

Comment: My code is not appearing so i posted below my code:                   <h:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="ex.show()">

            </h:commandButton>
            
            <p:dialog id="dialog1"  widgetVar="ex">
                <h:outputText value="Hi"/>
           </p:dialog>

Answer (score 3):

You can place `iframe` inside your dialog

Like this :

```
<h:form prependId="false">
<h:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="ex.show(); return false;"></h:commandButton>

<p:dialog id="dialog1"  widgetVar="ex"  onHide="jQuery('#someId').hide();" onShow="jQuery('#someId').show();">
    <iframe frameborder="0" align="left"
         src="http://www.primefaces.org"
         name="someName" id="someId" scrolling="auto" width="750"
         height="500" marginheight="5" marginwidth="10">
     </iframe>
</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

Second option could be placing `p:lightBox iframe="true"` inside your dialog and open it when the dialog is being opened , like this:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="ex.show(); return false;"></h:commandButton>

    <p:dialog id="dialog1"  widgetVar="ex" onShow="openLink()">
        <p:lightBox iframe="true">  
            <h:outputLink id="mylink" value="http://www.primefaces.org">  
            </h:outputLink>  
        </p:lightBox>  
    </p:dialog>
    <script>
        function openLink(){
            setTimeout("jQuery('#mylink').click();", 50);
        }
    </script>
</h:form>
```

Comment: But after the iframe opens if you click outside that iframe then it disappears and the p:dialog is shown. How to overcome it??

Comment: @user1788115 does it happen on my first solution ? cause the first one works just fine for me , also , If it works for you , you should mark the answer as accepted...

Comment: but the first one opens with close button and if I can pen it without header close button then it will be fine.. Second one is good but with the above mentioned problem.

Comment: you mean adding `closable=false` to the dialog ?